# Have git raise a merge conflict for differences between branches

Tags: git, github, merge

I have a github branch that has tons of changes that aren't on the main branch. When I attempt to merge the changes branch into the main branch, git automatically merges a significant amount of the content, and raises conflicts for instances in which the additions are directly integrated into existing html or javascript.

What I would like is for git to raise a merge conflict for all instances in which a difference exists between the two branches, so I could go through and approve every addition.

I have tried the 'ours' strategy, but this simply did a force merge, keeping all incoming changes from what I can tell.

Is there a way I can trigger a merge conflict for all differences between the two branches when merging them? Or a similar function that would facilitate the combining of these branches in a careful way? I'm aware of using git diff, but I was hoping something existed more like what occurs in resolving a merge conflict.

Comment: You could do something like `git checkout mainbranch && git reset new-branch` then review all the changes that it has made

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I would like is [...to] go through and approve every addition.

Git's automerge is built to spare you that, but if you don't want it you can shut it off and apply the individual differences by another method,

```
git merge --no-commit -s ours thatbranch
git checkout -p thatbranch -- .
```

This will prompt you for every difference between your current branch and the content on `thatbranch`, getting the "approve every addition" you're after.  `git commit` when you've got the merge results looking the way you want.

Comment: thank you. I tried that and it prompts for all the changes in terminal. do you know if there's a way for the changes to be prompted within vs code or a text editor?

Comment: You could try running a `git diff thatbranch >diffs` or `git diff ...thatbranch >diffs`, edit that file to remove any you don't like, then `git apply -3 <diffs`, Git's got a _lot_ of machinery for munging diffs, so much of it that once you stray from the beaten path, to avoid getting overwhelmed you really have to know what you're after before trying to figure out how.

Comment: That's not the same as a *merge* (though perhaps the OP isn't really looking for merge after all).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way I can trigger a merge conflict for all differences between the two branches when merging them?

No.  The problem actually lies in `git read-tree` (and the C code that implements it that `git merge` uses).  Read-tree just says:

- The commit in index slot 1 (merge-base) has hash H<sub>base</sub>.
- The commit in index slot 2 (`--ours`) has hash H<sub>ours</sub>.
- The commit in index slot 3 `(--theirs`) has hash H<sub>theirs</sub>.

  - If all three hashes match, use any copy, and we're done.
  - If H<sub>base</sub> = H<sub>theirs</sub>, use our copy H<sub>ours</sub>, and we're done.
  - If H<sub>base</sub> = H<sub>ours</sub>, use their copy H<sub>theirs</sub>, and we're done.
  - All three are different: do a low-level merge.
- "Done" means: discard staging slots 1-3; write the chosen hash ID into slot zero.

Merge conflicts *only* occur when the *low-level* merge declares one.  You can control which program, if any, is invoked to perform the low-level merge, but you cannot control the first three "if" tests.

> Or a similar function that would facilitate the combining of these branches in a careful way?

The closest you can come is to run `git merge --no-commit`, then, for each index entry—use `git ls-files --stage` to get them all—compare the hash ID in staging slot zero to those in the tree from the merge base.  That is:

1. Use `git merge-base --all` to find the merge base commit hash IDs.  If there are two or more, stop and get help, because now the problem is hard.  Otherwise, save this hash ID as the merge base hash ID.  In any case, you might also grab the other two hash IDs now (`git rev-parse HEAD` to get ours, and `git rev-parse merge-argument` to get theirs).
2. Create a temporary index and use `git read-tree` to fill it with files from the merge base.  (You can defer this step if it makes the coder simpler, which it probably will.)
3. Use (without the temporary index) `git merge` as usual but add `--no-commit`.  Consider inspecting the exit status, as 0 means "Git thinks all went well" and nonzero means "something went wrong"—including merge conflicts—but you might want to proceed even if Git thinks things went wrong.
4. Read the resulting index (with `git ls-files --stage`).  Every file that `git merge` thinks it merged successfully is in staging slot zero.  Every file that `git merge` thinks it *failed* to merge successfully has one or more entries in slots 1, 2, and/or 3.
5. Read the temporary index (with `git ls-files --stage` with the `GIT_INDEX_FILE` environment variable set appropriately).  For all the files that are in this index, if the corresponding file in the updated main index is at slot 0 but has a *different* hash ID, that means Git took that file from the `--ours` or `--theirs` commit(s).
6. For files that Git thinks it merged successfully, but which *don't* match the merge base, use `git update-index --index-info` to place the merge-base, ours, and theirs files into slots 1, 2, and 3, leaving the Git-thinks-the-merge-failed files alone (or updating them but the updates will be no-ops).  Watch out for files that are only in some, but not all 3, commits: their staging slots should be zero-ed to indicate that the file does not exist in that version.

There are some issues with renamed files here as well.  If Git thinks it merged successfully *with* the renaming accounted for, the file will be in slot zero under the new name.  The merge base name will have vanished and this new name will not be in the merge base commit.  You can make note of that, but note that if a new file was added in `--ours` or `--theirs` and not in the other commit, that file will *also* be in slot zero and not in the emerge base.

Mostly, though, the six steps above should produce the result you want: successfully-merged files will be considered "conflicted" and merge tools will see all three inputs.  You won't see any conflict *markers* in the *work-tree* copy of the file, but you'll know which files were which because `git status` will call them *unmerged*.